# How to plot a semicircle

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I plot a semicircle like the image below?
It doesn't matter the radius. The only condition is the center is in some positive value of `c_r` axis.

[image]

Comment: Did you see in the documentation for `Circle` that you can specify angles?

Comment: probably `Disk` if you want it filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To throw in my two cents

```
ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t] + 1.5, r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}, {r, 0, 1},
Frame -> False, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-1, 2}}]
```

with the result

[image]

Though there are also other possible solutions such as using `PolarPlot` or `Graphics` with appropriate set of graphic directives.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use `Plot`:

```
xc = 4;

myradius = 1;

Plot[If[Abs[x-xc]>myradius, 0, Sqrt[myradius^2 - (x - xc)^2]], 
{x, 0, 3 xc}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 4 xc}, {0, 2 myradius}},
Filling->Axis]
```